# What is wrong with my perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, shell, unix

I am trying to find bad records in a text file:

the format of the data in the file is:

```
somedata\x1Fsomemoredata\x1F\n
somedata2\x1Fsomemoredata2\x1F\n
```

(\x1F is the unit separator in hex value, this data is written out in another script using Perl's chr(31), which is the unit separator's ascii code)

I have written this is in perl:

```
## the format of each record in the file: alphanumericdata\x1Falphanumericdata\x1F\n
my $regex = "/[A-z0-9]+\\x1F[A-z0-9]+\\x1F\\n\$/";

print $regex;

#### just opening file
my $filename = "data.txt";
open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename)
   or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

### reading file line by line
while (my $row = <$fh>) {

   ## if line does not match format, print the culprit!!!
   if($row !~ $regex) {
       print $row;
   }
}

close $fh;
```

This prints each row but I know most of the rows are correctly formatted so something is off with my regex.

Am I committing some noob mistake here??

Comment: does your text literally have the characters ``\``, `x`, `1`, `F` in it (4 chars), or is that simply an escaped presentation of a single one-byte hex code (e.g. 0x1F = decimal 37)?

Comment: Aren't you making things unnecessarily difficult for yourself by trying to store a regex as a double quoted string? Use `qr()` -- it is what it is for.

Comment: the text does not have the literal character \,x,1,F.. that was just a representation of the UNIT separator from the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) @MarcB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are including the Perl match operator (Perl code) in your pattern.

```
my $pat = "^[A-z0-9]+\\x1F[A-z0-9]+\\x1F\\n\\z";

if ($row !~ m/$pat/)
if ($row !~ /$pat/)   # shortcut
if ($row !~ $pat)     # shortcut
```

---

It doesn't make sense to hardcode a pattern as a string literal, so let's pretend `$pat` is being read from a file. In that case, you'd want to pre-compile it.

```
# Pretend we're reading  ^[A-z0-9]+\x1F[A-z0-9]+\x1F\n\z  from a file.
my $pat = "^[A-z0-9]+\\x1F[A-z0-9]+\\x1F\\n\\z";

my $re = qr/$pat/;

if ($row !~ m/$re/)
if ($row !~ /$re/)   # shortcut
if ($row !~ $re)     # shortcut
```

If you were hardcoding a file, you'd use `qr//` directly. It saves you from escaping a bunch of slashes.

```
my $re = qr/^[A-z0-9]+\x1F[A-z0-9]+\x1F\n\z/;

if ($row !~ m/$re/)
if ($row !~ /$re/)   # shortcut
if ($row !~ $re)     # shortcut
```

In this case, there does not appear to be a reason to specify the pattern in advance. You could specify right in the match operator.

```
if ($row !~ m/^[A-z0-9]+\x1F[A-z0-9]+\x1F\n\z/)
if ($row !~ /^[A-z0-9]+\x1F[A-z0-9]+\x1F\n\z/)   # same
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `qr()`, which is the correct way to store a regex:

```
my $regex = qr([A-z0-9]+\x1F[A-z0-9]+\x1F\n$);
```